# Datagridview row select values from record not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql

I have a datagridview that is populated by a combo box with 1 column.  I need to be able to select that record and insert values not shown in the datagridview.  Normally I would do this when I populate the all the values needed:

```
newlien.LienReason = (string)row.Cells["LienType"].Value;
newlien.LienNumber = (string)row.Cells["LienNumber"].Value;
```

Which will not work as the cells are not being populated.  I am guessing that there are two solutions: either add the other columns and hide them and then pull the values from hidden cells or some way to get the values of the record without adding the values to the DGV. Either way I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. Are you trying to populate hidden columns in the datagridview? I can't seem to make sense of your problem. Can you add more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add the desired column(s) to your DGV and then set `visible` to false in those DGV column properties. Then you can still pull values from the hidden columns, just like you would from any other column:

```
//hidden column
newlien.AnotherVariable = (string)row.Cells["HiddenColumn"].Value;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sure that will work.  How can I set those visible = false in code when the DGV is built?

Comment: @korrowan Like this: `ColumnName.Visible = false;`

Comment: Awesome I ll give it a shot.  Never had to do this with a DGV populated via linq before so I normally just go set that in properties!  Thanks.

Comment: Another question.  I am populating the the DGV using this query:              var groups = (from c in db.GetTable<ComNameAdd>()
    where c.ComNameKeyConvert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue)
    select new { c.FullAdd, c.StreetNum, c.Street, c.Suffix, c.Unit,    c.City, c.State, c.Zip })  
dgvComIntAdd.DataSource = groups;

Comment: How do I actually set the visibility in this case?